# react native keep re-render the view every 10 ms when using AsyncStorage

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, asyncstorage

I am newbie in ReactNative. ( I am very familiar with Raw Android)

Yesterday when I was using AsyncStorage ( incorrectly I think) , I met a problem that the View kept re-rendering every n millionseconds.

my code:

```
import React,  { Component} from 'react';
import {Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native'
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"

export default class StorageDemo extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    AsyncStorage.setItem("visitTimes", 100)
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      visitTimes: 0
    }
  }

  readData = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("visitTimes")
      this.setState(
        {
          visitTimes: result,
          isLoaded: true
        }
      )
      console.info("== loaded, this.state: ")
    }catch(error){
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    this.readData()

    if(this.state.isLoaded){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>Loaded!  </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>Loading... </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

Also I opened a logcat window to check the log, I was shocked by the log: it kept re-rendering the View every 10 ms.

[image]

My environment:

- Android SDK: 27
- Windows
- ReactNative 0.55
- Device: VIVO Y67A ( Android 6.0 , 4G RAM)

code could be found here: https://github.com/sg552/react_native_lesson_demo/blob/master/screens/StorageDemo.js

I know my code is not correct (using async, await) , so my question is:

How to read from AsyncStorage and render it to page? How to correct my code?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Guy, take a look on life cycle of React like componentWillMount() and using it. Don't calculate anything in render() function please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the problem is that you are calling your func `this.readData()` inside the render, and that function itself is calling `setState` which whenever is called, changes the state, which triggers a re-render on the component. So in this situation you have caused an infinite loop in the code, because `setState` calls render, which in turn calls `setState` again and you run out of memory.

To fix this quickly, you can remove the function call from your render, and add it to a button, so its only called when you want it to. Something like this:

```
import React,  { Component} from 'react';
import {Image, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native'
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"

export default class StorageDemo extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      visitTimes: 0
    }
  }

  readData = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("visitTimes")
      this.setState(
        {
          visitTimes: result,
          isLoaded: true
        }
      )
      console.info("== loaded, this.state: ")
    }catch(error){
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  render() {

    if(this.state.isLoaded){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>Loaded! {this.state.visitTimes} </Text>
          <Button 
           onPress={() =>  {
            AsyncStorage.setItem("visitTimes", "100")
            this.setState({isLoaded: false})
            }} 
           title="Set Storage Item"
           />
        </View>
      )
    }else{
      return(
        <View>
          <Button 
          onPress={this.readData}
          title="Load from async storage"></Button>
        </View>
      )
    }

  }
}
```

Try this and this should give you the value from localStorage!

Comment: Thanks, quite clear about the relationships between 'state changing' and the 'rendering', this explains why I faced to the infinite loop rendering.

Comment: I'm glad I could help 